# How to add a property of existing name to a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object with the following properties

```
var a
id : "Something"
value : "Something"
```

I want to add another property with name id is it possible in javascript?

Comment: You have an object. but you don't show us the real object.Why would you want to add another `id` prop ?

Comment: You want to have two properties named `id`? So.... how will you distinguish between them when accessing `obj.id`...!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just have an array of ids:

```
var a = {
  id: ['id1','id2'],
  value: 'something'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this not possibly. In object keys is unique.